# Call function for all array elements without passing item as parameter

Tags: javascript, ruby

In javascript I can do this:

```
var show = function(w) {
  alert(w);
};

var words =  ['a', 'b', 'c'];
words.forEach(show);
```

Note that I don't need to pass the array item as a parameter.

Is there a way to the same in ruby?

Like:

```
def show(w)
  puts w
end

words = ['a', 'b', 'c']
words.each(show)
```

PS:
I know that I can do it by doing: `words.each { |w| show(w) }`. The question is if I can do it like in javascript, without passing the item as a parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you do it by passing the method, just like you do in ECMAScript:

```
words.each(&method(:show))
```

Note that this is the way to make your Ruby example work. However, a Ruby method is not really the closest analogue to an ECMAScript function in Ruby. A `Proc` would actually be a closer match:

```
show = -> w { puts w }

words.each(&show)
```

This actually reads very close to the ECMAScript 6 version:

```
const show = w => alert(w);

words.forEach(show);
```

Comment: Or make `show` a lambda and say `words.each(&show)`. That would probably be a closer match to the JavaScript version.

Comment: Nice one, Jörg. Early riser, eh?

Comment: @muistooshort: You're right, I was focused too much on making the OP's example work. Added.